# Aggregate sub-lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects (i.e. integers) and I want to aggregate sub-lists with LINQ.

For example:

*Original list:* `[ 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 10, 4, 12 ]`

*Sub-lists:* `[ [1,4,5,3], [4,5,3,4], [5,3,4,10], [3,4,10,4], [4,10,4,12] ]`

*Result (Aggregated List):* `[ 5, 5, 10, 10, 12 ]`

I want to create the maximum of a sub-list for each element containing itself and the following `n = 3` elements. Is this possible with LINQ or do I need to create my own aggregation mechanism?

Thanks in advance,Christian

Comment: How is the original list related to the "sub-lists"?

Comment: I assume it shows how sub-lists are created. But also don't see any relation to question

Comment: You need to be a little bit clearer in your question. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: I gather the sub-list takes an int + the next 3 to create a list

Comment: The sub-lists is a new list for each element that contains itself with the following `n = 3` elements. `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` will become `[[a,b,c,d],[b,c,d,e],[c,d,e,f]]`

Comment: And you is the result selected?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetSubLists(int[] collection)
{
   for(int i = 0; i< collection.Length - 3; i++)
       yield return collection.Skip(i).Take(4);
}

GetSubLists(original).Select(l => l.Max());
```

Or in one line

```
int[] original = {1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 10, 4, 12 };
int chunkCount = 4;
Enumerable.Range(0, original.Length - chunkCount + 1).Select(i => original.Skip(i).Take(chunkCount))
 .Select(l => l.Max());
```

Comment: Your last method produces `{ 5, 5, 10 }` instead of  `{ 5, 5, 10, 10, 12 }`. Also worth noting that skipping all items from original list on each iteration is very inefficient

Comment: Oops, right, should be + 1 instead of -1. Thanks, edited, agree regarding skip, but I have chosen array, which don't have appropriate GetRange method. for small arrays it is ok

Comment: The `GetSubLists` Method will produce chunks of smaller size than 4 at the end. `(new [] {1,2,3}).Take(4)` produces `{1,2,3}`

Comment: Please avoid l as a variable name. It is very easy to mistake for 1 or I.

Comment: Also, as Sergey pointed out, the repeated `Skip(x).Take(y)` is very inefficient as it leads to O(n^2) behavior. Each element is iterated over n times.

Comment: @3DGrabber this code is just a model, that will work for small arrays as expected... for big arrays there are a bunch of ways to simulate range or to copy new array

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = sublists.Select(sl => sl.Max());
// [5,5,10,10,12]
```

Creating sub-lists:

```
List<int> original = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 10, 4, 12 };
int sublistSize = 4; 
// check if original size is greater than required sublistSize
var sublists = Enumerable.Range(0, original.Count - sublistSize + 1)
                         .Select(i => original.GetRange(i, sublistSize));

// [[1,4,5,3],[4,5,3,4],[5,3,4,10],[3,4,10,4],[4,10,4,12]]
```

Comment: Is there a method to create the sublists automatically? `list.MAGIC_METHOD_TO_CREATE_SUBLISTS.Select(sl => sl.Max())`

Comment: @Greeny it was not clear that you want to create sublists. Updated answer with sublists creation

Answer (score 0):

```
    IEnumerable<int[]> GetLists (int[] list, int size )
    {
       return Enumerable.Range(0, list.Length - size + 1).Select(x => list.Skip(x).Take(size).ToArray());
    }
```

Sample:

```
    var list = new[] {1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 10, 4, 12};
    var max = GetLists(list, 4).Select(x => x.Max()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Sub-lists` intermediate result can be constructed with a "Sliding Window" function.

The desired `Result` then is the function `Max()` mapped over the windows with `Select()`.

```
var originalList = new [] {1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 10, 4, 12};
var sublists     = originalList.Window(4);            // [ [1,4,5,3], [4,5,3,4], ... ]
var result       = sublists.Select(Enumerable.Max);   // [ 5, 5, 10, 10, 12 ]
```

Efficient `Window` function:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Window<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                                                    int windowSize)
{
    if(windowSize < 1) throw new ArgumentException("windowSize must positive", "windowSize");

    var q = new Queue<T>(windowSize);
    foreach(var e in source)
    {
         q.Enqueue(e);
         if(q.Count < windowSize) continue; // queue not full yet

         yield return q;
         q.Dequeue();
    }
}
```